# Oracle Jet, Core Router - Reconfigure function

Tags: oracle-jet

In an Oracle Jet APP i'm trying to achieve some resource authorization behavior based on user authentication,

the idea is:

- Initiallize Router with only login route

This is the code used in AppController:

```
let navData = [
    { path: '', redirect: 'login' },
    { path: 'login', detail: { label: 'Login', iconClass: 'oj-ux-ico-information-s' } },        
  ];

  // Router setup
  this.router = new CoreRouter(navData, {
    urlAdapter: new UrlParamAdapter()
  });
        
  this.router.sync();
```

- Once user succesfully authenticates update router with protected routes

To achieve this i'm trying to use reconfigure function from Core Router based in this API:

https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jsdocs/CoreRouter.html#reconfigure

In this way

```
let routes = [                                
            { path: 'accounts' },
            { path: 'new' },                
        ];                         
          
        this.router.reconfigure(routes, {path: 'accounts'} );
        
        this.router.sync();
```

Unfortunately i get following error:

"Uncaught TypeError: this.router.reconfigure is not a function"

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: looks correct, are you sure you are using version 11? if yes perhaps catch the router in a breakpoint to see its shape or wrap it is a JSON.stringify(this.router) before reconfigure to get some more insight

Comment: Hi! Thanks por reply, i'm ar version 9.1.0 or oracle jet. The documentation states tha Core Router is from version 8, are you referefing to version 11 of oracle jet? Besides i do a console log of Router and this is what i shows (next reply):

Comment: perhaps using the latest version will fix the issue